# Orientation change giving blank space in iphone browser

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, mobile-website, screen-orientation

I have simple code like below

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>JSP Page</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            function fun(){
                alert(window.orientation);
            }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color: yellow;padding: 20px ">Hello World!</div>
    <input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="Hit Me" />
</body>
```

I am testing this code in Iphone.

Case 1: Iphone is Portrait, Once  I click on button alert will come. Now the  present in the browser will have 100% width (say 320px). Now change it to Landscape. Still the  shows the same 320px. It won't cover whole space ( say 480px ). It has some blank space at right.
But I need 100% ( to 480px ). Once we click on OK button of alert, it will cover to 480px.

Case 2: Same from Landscape to Portrait, but the gap will come at bottom.

How can I resolve this issue?

How can we cover  width to 100% in both the Portrait & Landscape with alert on that?

Do alert() of JavaScript will block all the events or UI state of browser?

Help me in this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about iOS...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

works well.  The problem you are having in iOS is what happens with BlackBerry and Android with this method though.